# Android inputtype troubles

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, textwatcher

What i have to do:

I'm implementing some kind of fancy calculator for special measurements. For this, i have a ListView with sever edit texts.
Per row are tow EditTexts where the user shall be able to enter decimal values.

What my problem is:

I have set inputType both in code and xml, but i get weird behavior out of this. After tapping any number, the normal keyboard pops up for like half a second, then switching back to the decimal keyboard.

I guess the problem comes from me calling requestFocus() on the currently active EditText. But in the way my Calculator needs to work, i have to do this, since every change from the user results in a recalculation of my values (therefore, updating the whole list view --> results in loss of focus which shall be prevented)

Important Code Snippets so far:

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TextValue"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:background="#E6E6E6"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="@string/Ung"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        />
```

(Same code for second EditText in row)

RequestFocus is called in the getView method of my ArrayAdapter, since Reloading --> Loss of Focus --> ...

```
....
        if (position == currentTag) {
            textValue.requestFocus();
        }
....
```